# Image Upload & Data Collection in Single Form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to create a photo competition upload form, much like the one that can be found [here](http://www.sandiegozoo.org/absolutelyapes/photoform.php). I expect to get less than 40 entries per month.

I've managed to mash together a image upload form that places the image in a specific folder on the server – see the code [here](http://opna.ir/Fx3z).

I really have no idea what the next step is, do I have to create a database, or can I instruct the form to create a .txt file with all the other input data? Am I better off to try to create a email POST that includes the image as a attachment.

I've tried searching for a tutorial on how to do something, but have not found anything useless.

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated, as I'm a self taught novice.

Answer (score 2):

I would say your best bet is to create a database. Then you can upload the details of each entry to the db with the stored url of the image.
 eg. On form submit the data is entered into the db, your upload script for the image is run and the image name is entered into the db along with the other data.

Comment: Thanks, but that's just out of my skill set. Decided to go with a free [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com) account instead which includes 100mb of storage and 100 submissions per month. Styling's a annoying though.